# Cannot add a new Topology Manager Mapping

Tags: web8, topology-manager, discovery-service

After following the steps in [Error while updating Discovery Service Registrations](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14867/error-while-updating-discovery-service-registrations) I am faced with a new problem.

When I try to add a new mapping to an existing WebApplication like below

```
Add-TtmMapping -PublicationID tcm:0-18-1 -WebApplicationID Website1_RootWebApp -RelativeUrl /dev/en/ -CmEnvironmentId Tridioncm_WWCMCEO1000DIT
```

I get the error

> Add-TtmMapping : Unable to save item of type 'MappingData' with id
>   'Mapping6'. One or more errors occurred. An error occurred while
>   communicating with CD Discovery Service
>   'http://url:8082/discovery.svc'
>   in CD Environment 'CdEnvironment1'. Error performing batch request 400
>   BAD REQUEST The related used by item doesn't exist in database:
>   Website1_RootWebApp

This part is strange, **item doesn't exist in database: Website1_RootWebApp**

Tracing this backwards, trying to find the error, I've explored the following

Is the WebApplication Id correct? **Yes**

```
Get-TtmWebApplication

ContextUrl           : /
WebsiteId            : Website1
EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
CdEnvironment        :
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : Website1_RootWebApp
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

Does the WebApplication exist in CdEnvironment1? **Yes**

```
Get-TtmWebsite

BaseUrls             : {http://url}
CdEnvironmentId      : CdEnvironment1
EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
CdEnvironment        :
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {}
Id                   : Website1
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

So I am not sure why I am getting this error.

When I check on the Topology Manager side, I see similar answers

**/ttm201501/CdEnvironments**

```
{
 "@odata.context":"http://url:81/ttm201501/$metadata#CdEnvironments","value":[
    {
      "Id":"CdEnvironment1","ExtensionProperties":[

      ],"ScopedRepositoryKeys":[
],"EnvironmentPurpose":"Staging","DiscoveryEndpointUrl":"http://url:8082/discovery.svc","Credentials":{
        "@odata.type":"#Tridion.TopologyManager.Client.AnonymousServiceCredentials","AuthenticationType":"Anonymous"
      },"IsOffline":false
    }
  ]
}
```

**/ttm201501/Websites**

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://url:81/ttm201501/$metadata#Websites","value":[
    {
      "Id":"Website1","ExtensionProperties":[

      ],"ScopedRepositoryKeys":[

      ],"BaseUrls":[
        "http://url"
      ],"CdEnvironmentId":"CdEnvironment1","EnvironmentPurpose":"Staging"
    }
  ]
}
```

**/ttm201501/WebApplications**

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://url:81/ttm201501/$metadata#WebApplications","value":[
    {
      "Id":"Website1_RootWebApp","ExtensionProperties":[

      ],"ScopedRepositoryKeys":[

      ],"ContextUrl":"/","WebsiteId":"Website1","EnvironmentPurpose":"Staging"
    }
  ]
}
```

**/ttm201501/Mappings**

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://url:81/ttm201501/$metadata#Mappings","value":[
    {
      "Id":"Mapping2","ExtensionProperties":[

      ],"CmEnvironmentId":"Tridioncm_WWCMCEO1000DIT","PublicationId":"tcm:0-9-1","EnvironmentPurpose":"Staging","WebApplicationId":"Website1_RootWebApp","RelativeUrl":"/ww/en","PrimaryMappedUrl":"http://url/ww/en","IsOffline":false
    },{
      "Id":"Mapping5","ExtensionProperties":[

      ],"CmEnvironmentId":"Tridioncm_WWCMCEO1000DIT","PublicationId":"tcm:0-16-1","EnvironmentPurpose":"Staging","WebApplicationId":"Website1_RootWebApp","RelativeUrl":"/ww/fr","PrimaryMappedUrl":"http://url/ww/fr","IsOffline":false
    }
  ]
}
```

I **think** that the problem could be the following

Before executing steps in [Error while updating Discovery Service Registrations](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14867/error-while-updating-discovery-service-registrations) DefaultWeb (in my discovery database) was Website1_RootWebApp

If I sync with WebCapability commented out, there is no DefaultWeb

If I sync with WebCapability included, I have two DefaultWeb rows, each with a GUID. There is no sign of Website1_RootWebApp

Comment: Can you also try to sync Topology Manager items then? Using cmdlet 'Sync-TtmCdEnvironment -Id CdEnvironment1' and check if it will return any errors. This command should delete all previous data related to Topology Manager items in Discovery service and re-create them again. Topology Manager items will not be touched though.

Comment: If all else fails, you could recreate your Discovery Service DB, register the Capabilities again and then use `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment` to synchronize with Topology Manager.

Comment: Stan, if you can expand that into and answer you win the prize

Comment: I had the same issue. I ran Sync-TtmCdEnvironment and then Add-TtmMapping worked.

Comment: Sync-TtmCdEnvironment is the best way to fix it. make sure discovery.svc is accessible from your CMS.

Answer (score 4):

`Sync-TtmCdEnvironment` is the best way to fix it. make sure discovery.svc is accessible from your CMS